# Regex join query optimization in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

How can I optimize this query below, it `took 8 hrs to run` :

```
create table rtime.rtime_calc1_jun13tojun19 as(
    explain select pa.api as pa_api, pa.action_type as pa_action_type, max(rt.request_time), avg(rt.request_time), 
                                                               percentile_cont(0.95) within group (order by rt.request_time asc) as percentile_95
    from  public.public_api pa,
          (select reqtime.* from public.public_api puba 
           right join rtime.rtime_data1_jun13tojun19 reqtime
           on puba.api = reqtime.proxy
           where puba.api is null) as rt   -- to join only regex patterns, and to prevent exact static matches from becoming a part of regex join
    where rt.proxy ~* pa.api_regex
    and   rt.method = pa.action_type
    group by pa.api, pa.action_type
)
```

Below is it's EXPLAIN Plan :

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=1131.43..263846.61 rows=1 width=70)
  Group Key: pa.api, pa.action_type
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1131.43..263846.59 rows=1 width=54)
        Join Filter: (((reqtime.proxy)::text ~* (pa.api_regex)::text) AND ((reqtime.method)::text = (pa.action_type)::text))
        ->  Index Scan using primary_key_pa on public_api pa  (cost=0.28..565.81 rows=2007 width=90)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=1131.16..263245.66 rows=1 width=49)
              ->  Gather  (cost=1131.16..263245.65 rows=1 width=49)
                    Workers Planned: 2
                    ->  Hash Anti Join  (cost=131.16..262245.55 rows=1 width=49)
                          Hash Cond: ((reqtime.proxy)::text = (puba.api)::text)
                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on rtime_data1_jun13tojun19 reqtime  (cost=0.00..218885.08 rows=5763908 width=49)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=106.07..106.07 rows=2007 width=42)
                                ->  Seq Scan on public_api puba  (cost=0.00..106.07 rows=2007 width=42)
```

The `public.public_api` table has `2007` rows. 
The `rtime.rtime_data1_jun13tojun19` table has `13837305 rows` in it.

Here is the DDL for `public_api` table :

```
CREATE TABLE public.public_api (
    api varchar NOT NULL,
    "type" varchar NULL,
    api_bin varchar NULL,
    api_bin_avg_resp_time varchar NULL,
    api_bin_perc95_resp_time varchar NULL,
    max_response_time float8 NULL,
    avg_response_time float8 NULL,
    percentile_95_response_time float8 NULL,
    max_tps int4 NULL,
    min_tps int4 NULL,
    avg_tps float8 NULL,
    percentile_90_tps float8 NULL,
    percentile_99_tps float8 NULL,
    percentile_95_tps float8 NULL,
    product varchar NULL,
    action_type varchar NOT NULL,
    proxy varchar NULL,
    CONSTRAINT primary_key_pa PRIMARY KEY (api, action_type)
);
```

Here is the DDL for `rtime.rtime_data1_jun13tojun19`

```
CREATE TABLE rtime.rtime_data1_jun13tojun19 (
    env varchar NULL,
    proxy varchar NULL,
    "method" varchar NULL,
    request_time float8 NULL
);
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: @dmg: basically how can this query be optimized?, it is currently taking 8 hrs to run